# MongoDB save() method and version control

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, concurrency

Is it correct to assume that because the save() method has built-in version control you do not need to worry about concurrent updates and losing information if you execute your all updates to your data via the save() method?

For example:

1. get doc from db
2. apply business logic: applyBusinessLogic(doc)
3. doc.save()

If you try to save a document that has changed due to a successful update from another process you will get an error of nature *No matching document found for id "5f2bf3059adb51a6f8a3eda3" version 1 modifiedPaths "alerts"*. So then you know that the business logic that you applied is potentially no longer valid because the document has changed, giving you the opportunity to retry or handle this situation.

I have read various posts relating to optimistic concurrency in MongoDB - for example, https://jimmybogard.com/document-level-optimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb/. However, I do not see why you would need to implement such a solution when the built-in version control can already achieve this.

Comment: If you are asking about documented behavior, link to the documentation describing the behavior.

Comment: The first paragraph of that blog post appears to contradict https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency.